# Get records from table 1 which are not presented in table 2

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this query:

```
SELECT `product`.`id`, `title` AS `text` FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `productlang` ON product.id=productlang.product_id 
LEFT JOIN `new_product` ON product.id=new_product.product_id 
WHERE (`product`.`id` <> `new_product`.`product_id`) 
AND (`title` LIKE '%nik%') 
AND (`language`='bg') 
LIMIT 20
```

The purpose is to get all products from `product` table whose `id` doesn't exist in `new_product` (`product_id` is the related column).I tought `WHERE (product.id <> new_product.product_id)` part should do the trick. Where is my bad ? Thank you!

Comment: title and language are in which table ?

Comment: In `productlang`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whenever using `Left Join`, please ensure that your `Where` conditions on the right-side table of a `Left Join` are specified in the `On` clause. Otherwise, this would limit your result-set.
- To check if there is no matching entry in the right-side table, we can use `IS NULL`.
- Please use proper [aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) when dealing with multi-table queries, for readability and clarity purposes.

Try the following:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       pl.title AS `text` 
FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN productlang AS pl  
  ON p.id = pl.product_id AND 
     pl.title LIKE '%nik%' AND 
     pl.language = 'bg' 
LEFT JOIN new_product AS np 
  ON p .id = np.product_id 
WHERE np.product_id IS NULL 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: It can be `NULL`. The record is there or not.

Comment: After the edit now it did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TomaTomov happy to help. do check the added explanation.

Comment: Checking it right now :D Thank you for it ! Appreciate that type of answers :)